# How to use fabric with juju

Tags: ssh, juju, django, fabric

I'm using the python-django charm to deploy a small django-based site, with the [local provider](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/config-local) for test purposes. So far the deployment itself has worked, but I'd like to be able to manage the site without having to `juju ssh` into it.

So I'm trying to use fabric as described on the [python-django charm documentation](https://jujucharms.com/python-django), but whenever I try to execute a task with `fab`, I'm being asked for `"Login password for 'ubuntu': "`. That is, it seems that SSH authentication does not work. Here's what it looks like:

```
# Get fabfile.py from the charm code
bzr branch lp:charms/python-django 
cd python-django
fab -R ubucon-site/7 pull
[10.0.3.252] Executing task 'pull'
[10.0.3.252] sudo: find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
[10.0.3.252] Login password for 'ubuntu':
```

As an additional note, there seems to be a [Juju fabric plugin](https://gist.github.com/avoine/5065738) around, which is based on the same code as the one in the python-django charm, so the fabfile.py file might actually be generic and not specific to the python-django charm.

Any ideas on how to be able to use fabric with juju? Or any pointers on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Fabric is using standard `ssh` instead of `juju ssh` (which uses the Juju ssh key).  The easiest way to get the auth to work is to import your ssh key from Launchpad into your Juju deployment:

```
juju authorized-keys import $launchpad_user
```